# $cart->add_fee max out at 100

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want a deduction of 200 amount from the cart total. For that I have this code. But it deducts only 100 from each cart item. Why is that?

```
function correction_of_deposit_cart( $cart ) {
  $cart->add_fee( __( 'Correction', 'correctionofdeposit' ) , -200 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'correction_of_deposit_cart' );
```

Comment: Actually it is maxing out at subtotal's amount. So if subtotal is 130, it maxes out at 130 even 200 is put in code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function addDiscount($cart){
    $discount = 200;
    $cart->add_fee('Member discount', -$discount, false, 'zero-rate');
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'addDiscount');
```

& this:

```
// exclude discount from taxes
function excludeCartFeesTaxes($taxes, $fee, $cart){
    return [];
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_get_fees_from_cart_taxes', excludeCartFeesTaxes', 10, 3);
```

further details here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/21148

Comment: It didn't work. Here is the link - 
https://f2test.xn--saunamobil-thringen-ibc.de/